# Reset stored Windows 7 file sharing password

Tags: windows-7

I have an Ubuntu server setup running samba. I was able to successfully connect and authenticate using my account for the Ubuntu box. I had to change my password on the Ubuntu machine and now I can't connect.

It doesn't ask me for a new username/password, it just says, "You do not have permission to access". I know there is just a setting somewhere that I need to change. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that windows keeps the connection to the server open even though you aren't using it. In order to force it to close go into the command prompt and type

```
c:> net use
```

and then use

```
c:> net use /delete <connection>
```

to finish it off.

I found the solution here.

http://travisepperson.blogspot.com/2007/01/windows-network-folder-specified-is.html

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Credential Manager of Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) to delete the old username/password and enter the new data.

[image]
(Imagesource: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/systems-administrator/migrating-saved-website-and-terminal-services-passwords-with-windows-7-credential-manager-102201)

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't have any saved credentials there.